# I can not put my image in the ImageView in Vistual Editor well and exact

Tags: android

My question is simple but important.please see the image below.I can put buttons as row and exact.I try to drag and drop the image but I can not put my image as row and exact in the screen like the buttons.It seems there is no a certain rule!

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ccc"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"/>
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
................
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button10" android:layout_below="@+id/button" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_marginRight="33dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Please vote for me because I want upload an image.**

[image]

Comment: I want upload an image for more information please vote for me.

Comment: Provide your full layout and a picture for better understanding (via picture hosting website if you don't have enough reputation).

Comment: thank you. stackoverflow has good users.thank you. I want  to move and resize the my image optionally and of course exactly in screen.

Comment: I want move my image upward or down or left and or right using the unit millimeters.